# Difference between startTime and endTime for groups of tasks

Tags: sql, date, group-by

I have a table that has three columns.

- When the task was supposed to start (nominalStartTime)
- When it did start (startTime)
- When it ended (endTime)

There around a bunch of tasks that are scheduled to run every 15 minutes. I need to know the difference between when the first task started and when the last task ended. For example, see below

```
  NominalStartTime  |  startTime  |   endTime
____________________|_____________|____________
2012-09-19 08:15:00 | 08:15:41.27 | 08:15:47.00
2012-09-19 08:15:00 | 08:15:45.13 | 08:15:45.43
2012-09-19 08:15:00 | 08:15:49.88 | 08:15:50.13
2012-09-19 08:30:00 | 08:30:25.27 | 08:30:26.00
2012-09-19 08:30:00 | 08:30:45.13 | 08:30:45.43
2012-09-19 08:30:00 | 08:30:49.88 | 08:30:50.13
```

I'm looking for the query to return

```
  NominalStartTime  |  startTime  |   endTime   | difference
____________________|_____________|_____________|____________
2012-09-19 08:15:00 | 08:15:41.27 | 08:15:50.13 | 00:00:08.86
2012-09-19 08:30:00 | 08:30:25.27 | 08:30:50.13 | 00:00:24.86
```

I tried this but I'm getting aggregate group by errors and the like

```
Select NominalStart, MIN(TimeStarted) as TimeStarted, MAX(TimeEnded) as TimeEnded, DATEDIFF(ms, TimeStarted, TimeEnded)
FROM taskRuns
GROUP BY NominalStart
ORDER BY NominalStart
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
select NominalStart,min(TimeStarted),max(TimeEnded),
       DATEDIFF(ms ,min(TimeStarted),max(TimeEnded)) as difference
from taskRuns
group by NominalStart
order by NominalStart
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6505/12/0) Demo

Comment: that only returned one row. I'm not sure what it is doing exactly to be able to edit it

Comment: Did you see sql fiddle? There are two rows.

Comment: i did. I'm not sure why it worked there. I should have a couple thousand rows returned. As what I provided is only a small subset of data. And thoughts?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? I thought is MS Sql Server. Is your example is for one task? May solution shows you start time and end time for one task (I think). Have you got an information in taskRuns about tasks? TaskID or something?

Comment: It is ms sql server 2008r2. There are anywhere between 15 and 50 tasks that get kicked off. But their nominal start time is all the same. My example is for two sets of nominal start times but my full data set has hundreds. edit, my example only has 8:15 and 8:30, however I have all increments of 5 minutes and 15 minutes for weeks

Comment: Oh, now I see :). I edited the post. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Timestamps?

This stores time values as an amount of seconds from the start of 1970

Making it really easy to manipulate times and dates, you can simply subtract one from the other. It really depends what you're using to manipulate the data, php works very well with timestamps.

I'd take a look into storing the dates as timestamps if I were you...

Comment: the data is recorded by software that i don't control. unfortunately i have to operate within these bounds